# Vue filters not found in this.$options

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I've refactored my code and separated global filters, components and mixins.

And I could use filter as traditional way like shown below

```html
<span>{{ someNumber | ceil }}</span>
```

But I couldn't use filters from javascript of some component like

```js
const ceilNumber = this.$options.filters.ceil(this.someNumber);
```

I've created plain js file for my filter looks like

```js
// path: src/plugins/filters.js

const ceilFunction = (value) => {
  return Math.ceil(value);
};

export default {
  install(Vue) {
    Vue.filter('ceil', ceilFunction);
  }
}
```

And imported in main.js

```js
...
import Filters from '@/plugins/filters';

Vue.use(Filters);
...
```

UPDATE: I've found out that my filters created but it registered as variable not function. The error I'm getting when I called from javascript

```
TypeError: _this.$options.filters.ceil is not a function
    at eval (list.vue?51fc:156)
    at arrayMap (lodash.js?2ef0:653)
    at Function.map (lodash.js?2ef0:9622)
    at VueComponent._callee$ (list.vue?51fc:147)
    at tryCatch (runtime.js?96cf:65)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (runtime.js?96cf:303)
    at Generator.prototype.<computed> [as next] (runtime.js?96cf:117)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (asyncToGenerator.js?3b8d:5)
    at _next (asyncToGenerator.js?3b8d:27)
```

UPDATE 2: At the moment I could not use traditional usage. But I implemented empty project as I described above it works like a charm.

CONCLUSION: I've made a mistake on that exporting shown below

```js
export default {
  install(Vue) {
    Vue.filter('ceil', ceilFunction()); // actually called the function by mistake
    Vue.filter('currency', currency);
    Vue.filter('currencyAccounting', currencyAccounting);
    Vue.filter('percent', percent);
    Vue.filter('remainingDay', remainingDay);
  },
};
```